# What is the correct Google Analytics event tracking syntax?

Tags: events, google-analytics, tracking

Can anyone tell me if this is the correct syntax to use for Google Analytics event tracking?

```
<img onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Chair', 'Model', 'CB65 BLUE']);" id="thumbs" height="60" src="/some_image.png">
```

The tracking code:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);



(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1', 'XXXXXXX.net');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Answer (score 7):

You are mixing up two different types of GA code. The library you have added is **anlaytics.js** and for it , follow the below codes:

1, Set property id and track pageview

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1', 'XXXXXXX.net');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

2, Event tracking

```
ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'action', 'label');
```

An example of a button click would look like:

```
var downloadLink = document.getElementById('button');
addListener(downloadLink, 'click', function() {
  ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'nav-buttons');
});
```

The **_gaq.push** statement is used if your using the library **ga.js**

Comment: Thanks for the response, so inline would look like:

    <img onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'Chair', 'Model', 'C75 RED');" src="/some_img.jpg" width="72" height="72" alt="" height="74"/>

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the new version of Analytics (= Universal), make sure you check the official documentation: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

Comment: Thank you! This documentation seems hard to find! Searching google I could only find results relating to the old `_gaq.push('_trackEvent'...` or `_trackEvent(...`!

Comment: If you goole "analytics.js" you should always get relevant documentation only for Universal Analytics. Hope that everything is now working correctly :-)